# Geodjango using defer in manager causing keyerror on save

Tags: django, deferred, geodjango

I have several location models that each have a MultiPolygonField called mpoly, I noticed when getting a queryset or listing in the Django admin it's really slow so I made a default manager to defer the mpoly field:

```
class WithoutMpolyManager(models.Manager):

def get_queryset(self):
    return super(WithoutMpolyManager, self).get_queryset().defer('mpoly')
```

This speeds things up a lot in the admin and getting a queryset where I don't need the mpoly field, getting a single instance allows access to the mpoly field fine. The problem is when I want to save an instance in the admin or otherwise I get the error:

```
File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 692, in save
isinstance(self.__class__.__dict__[f.attname], DeferredAttribute))
KeyError: 'name'
```

name is another field that is not being deferred, is there anyway to fix this or another way to speed up querys like admin listing where mpoly is not needed?